# How to activate /showIncludes flag?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

How to activate /showInclude flag via command line , not using this instruction

"To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment
Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see How to: Open Project Property Pages.
Click the C/C++ folder.
Click the Advanced property page.
Modify the Show Includes property."

For some reason I do not have C/C++ folder in my Project Property pages, so I need some other way to define.

Answer (score 1):

This option corresponds to `/showIncludes` compiler switch.

You can add it directly to your command line.

However, it is strange that you Project Properties doesn't have C/C++; is your project written in C++?